# Lanczos algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $T ∈ R^{n×n}$ be symmetric tridiagonal, let $z ∈ R^n$ , and let $A = T + zz^T.$ Show how to use the symmetric Lanczos algorithm to produce an orthogonal $V ∈ R^{n×n}$ such that $V^TAV = \hat{T}$ where $\hat{T}$ is tridiagonal. Your procedure should require $O(n^2)$ operations. What is the ideal choice for $v_1 = V e_1$ for this procedure?

1. In the above question, what should be the ideal choice for $v_1$? Isn't it supposed to be a random unit vector?
2. And what is the significance of $A = T + zz^T$? Can't it be applied to any hermitian matrix A?

Comment: While you can apply Lanczos to any Herimitian matrix, that would require $n^3$ operations ($n^2$ operations for each of the $n$ steps). So you must use the structure here to get the $n^2$ operations. The choice of $v_1$ probably depends a bit on what is meant by ideal.

Comment: Do you know what structure $A = T + zz^T$ has because I can't relate it to any structure which will reduce the number of operations.

Comment: Think about how you could multiply $Av$ for some vector $v$ in less than $n^2$ time.